# One Dataset for each DataTable or one Dataset for all DataTables?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, dataset, local

I am writing a C# application that uses Local DataSets. 
I have a DataSet for Customer Information, and a DataSet for Stocked Items.
In regards to perfomance, and file size, would it be advisable to use just one DataSet with the Customer Infomation and the Stocked Items DataTables, or separate DataSets for each DataTable?
I intend to use data to put into a report (using report viewer).

Comment: Depends on if you need to link these tables. If the tables are not related and you don't need both always stay with separate `DataSet`s, otherwise put the tables in one dataset.

Comment: I was going to generate a report (with report viewer)with data from each datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSet` is built for, well just that, a *set of data.* It's built to allow you to create relationships between tables, provide cascading, and constraints. You should use data sets to group tables together when you are working with *more than one table at a time.* If you're not working with more than one table, get rid of the `DataSet` and just use a `DataTable`.

Now, if you're trying to *cache* all of the data locally, then that would make sense for all the tables to be in *one `DataSet`* where the data can be related and operated on together. Well, that is *if you're operating on those tables **together**.*

**UPDATE:** based on your comment about your intentions, it makes sense for all of the related data to exist in a single `DataSet`. The report is going to need to be able to know what rows are related and in what ways to handle grouping and such.

Comment: Thank you!Is there a way of combining pre-existing data from 2 datasets into just the 1?

Comment: @user3237403: Yeah, you'd want to look into the `DataTable.Copy` method to copy the structure and data of one into another.

Comment: There isn't that much to the tables anyway, I may just do it from scratch to jog my memory of how its done. Thanks!

Comment: @user3237403: sounds good, and I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Its also my first successful question, all my others were put on hold.